# App appearing on Android Market (Google Play) as twice its size?

Tags: android, google-play, apk

I have an apk which is 13.5MB. When I upload it to Google Play it shows as 27MB. When you start the download, however, you'll see the progress bar going from 0 to 13.5MB (as it should) rather than 0 to 27MB (as advertised on Google Play). Quite strange. Anyone else experienced this or know why it's happening?

If you want to see for yourself, this is the app:

[htps://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.projectzebra.bunkerbuster](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.projectzebra.bunkerbuster)

Comment: That's really odd, I haven't seen that happen. Looking through the apps I've downloaded in the last few days, the sizes all match the sizes listed on Google Play.

Comment: I seriously doubt the compression rate is 50%

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because the Copy Protection feature in Publishing Options was enabled. Disabling this feature, re-uploading my apk and saving changes (in the Edit Application page of Android Developer Console) got it down to its proper size.

Comment: You don't need to re-upload the apk file.  Turn off the copy protection, and wait a few hours, the size will go down by half.

Answer (score 0):

It is probably measuring its decompressed (installation) size. After all, APK's are actually ZIP files.